# C# Post request

Tags: c#, post, null

Необходимо отправить POST запросом XML файл. При получении ответа получаю ошибку java.Lang.NullPointerException. Сначала в XML файле содержались ошибки, сейчас ошибки поправили. Файл должен быть в кодировке windows-1251 и содержать шапку. Совместно с тех.поддержкой выяснили, что запрос приходит пустой. Подскажите пожалуйста, что надо сделать чтобы запрос пришел не пустой?

Вот код моей программы:

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
class Program
{
    public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        using (MemoryStream rms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            input.CopyTo(rms);
            return rms.ToArray();
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(

        new XDeclaration("1.0", "Windows-1251","yes"),
        new XElement("product",
            new XElement ("prequest",
            new XElement("req",
            new XElement("AddressReq",
                new XElement("houseNumber", "1"),
                new XElement ("street","Го"),
                new XElement("apartment", "38"),
                new XElement("city", "Магадан"),
                new XElement("postal", "685"),
                new XElement("addressType", "1")),
            new XElement("AddressReq",
                new XElement("houseNumber", "1"),
                new XElement("street", "Го"),
                new XElement("apartment", "38"),
                new XElement("city", "Магадан"),
                new XElement("postal", "685"),
                new XElement("addressType", "1")),
            new XElement("IdReq",
                new XElement("idNum", "273"),
                new XElement("idType","21"),
                new XElement("seriesNumber", "64"),
                new XElement("issueCountry", "г. Магадан"),
                new XElement("issueDate", "2006-03-18"),
                new XElement("issueAuthority", "ОВД")
            ),
            new XElement("IdReq",
                new XElement("idNum", "12345678901"),
                new XElement("idType", "32")
            ),
            new XElement("InquiryReq",
                new XElement("ConsentReq",
                    new XElement("consentFlag", "Y"),
                    new XElement("consentDate", "2016-01-20"),
                    new XElement("consentExpireDate", "2021-10-21"),
                     new XElement("consentPurpose", "4"),
                    new XElement("otherConsentPurpose", "Job pre-screening"),
                    new XElement("reportUser", "DG Human Resources Incorporated"),
                    new XElement("liability", "Y")
                ),
                 new XElement("inqPurpose", "01"),
                 new XElement("inqAmount", "10000"),
                 new XElement("currencyCode", "usd")
            ),
             new XElement("PersonReq",
                new XElement("name1", "К"),
                new XElement("first", "Г"),
                new XElement("paternal", "Г"),
                new XElement("gender", "1"),
                new XElement("birthDt", "1946-07-06"),
                new XElement("placeOfBirth", "Москва")
            ),
             new XElement("RequestorReq",
                new XElement("MemberCode", "code"),
                new XElement("UserID", "user"),
                new XElement("Password", "pass")
            ),
             new XElement("RefReq",

                new XElement("product", "CHST")
            ),
             new XElement("IOType","B2B"),
             new XElement("OutputFormat", "xml"),
             new XElement("lang", "ru")
            ))               
            ));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        xdoc.Save(stream);


        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("MyUrl");
        var byteArray = ReadFully(stream);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream data = request.GetRequestStream();
        data.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        data.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Нажмите клавишу чтобы получить ответ");
        Console.ReadKey();



        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        data = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        reader.Close();
        data.Close();
        response.Close();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Что значит пустой? Вы как то проверяете, что отправляете? Они каждый запрос записывают? Может они запрос не смогли разобрать, хотя запрос не пустой?  Установите Fiddler и смотрите все исходящие от вашего ПО запросы

Comment: Не, у них есть специальный сервис, который позволяет отладку делать. Я туда запрос отправил. А в логе у них пишется результат обработки. Я пробовал stream который отправляю сохранять в бинарный файл, и он пуст был(

Comment: то есть у вас не считываются данные из потока. `ReadFully` - покажите код функции

Comment: Джон Скит рулит: [Convert XDocument to Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8389472/5275890)

Answer (score 0):

Вы и так записали в стрим вот здесь данные

```
xdoc.Save(stream);
```

Но, как я понял, вы не двигаете записанный стрим в начало перед чтением

```
xdoc.Save(stream);
stream.Position = 0;
```